# Voted 40 times in close queue on Sept 11, 2014

Tags: support, review, vote-to-close

Normally we can vote on just 20 questions in the close queue, but yesterday the limit was increased to 40 questions.  Today the limit is 20 again.

Was this just a mistake?

I was hoping that it was a permanent change, as the queue grows slightly longer each day, so it can never be cleared out, which makes me sad panda.

P.S. As of now (16:39Z), I was able to vote on a 21st question.  Perhaps the limit is a moving target.

Comment: Do you recall at what *time* you started and ended?

Comment: @CanadianLuke The log on the site says it was 01:16Z to 16:10Z on 2014-09-11

Comment: Maybe the system has imprinted upon you as its mother because you talk to it 10000% more than anyone else.

Comment: Thanks for doing all the reviews that I'm too lazy to do, BTW.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Welcome to inflation. Or at least the close votes queue.

> [Currently, we allow 20 reviews per user per queue per day, but we double this to 40 if the queue size is over 1000.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152200/how-come-my-vote-cap-for-first-posts-is-lower-than-others/152233#152233)

So long as the close waiting count is above 1000, then you'll be able to use 40 from the queue.

Other times, it will shrink back down to 20 if under 1000.

Comment: My screen shows fewer than 800 questions in the queue.  Maybe it's not including questions that I already voted on?

Comment: Correct. Currently shows 1000+ here.